# Running Azure SDK for Go return an error: MSI not available

Tags: go, goland, azure-sdk

I am trying to run Golang Azure SDK code to get a list of RGs in my subscriptions but I am getting the following error:

**2022/01/22 20:25:58 MSI not available
exit status 1**

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/resources/mgmt/2020-10-01/resources"
    "github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/azure/auth"
    "github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/to"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    authorize, err := auth.NewAuthorizerFromEnvironment()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    subscriptionID := os.Getenv("AZURE_SUB_ID")

    //Read resource groups
    resGrpClient := resources.NewGroupsClient(subscriptionID)
    resGrpClient.Authorizer = authorize

    //Read resources within the resource group
    resClient := resources.NewClient(subscriptionID)
    resClient.Authorizer = authorize

    for resGrpPage, err := resGrpClient.List(context.Background(), "", nil); resGrpPage.NotDone(); err = resGrpPage.Next() {

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        for _, resGrp := range resGrpPage.Values() {
            fmt.Println("Resource Group Name: ", to.String(resGrp.Name))
            resList, _ := resClient.ListByResourceGroup(context.Background(), to.String(resGrp.Name), "", "", nil)

            for _, res := range resList.Values() {
                fmt.Println("\t- Resource Name: ", to.String(res.Name), " | Resource Type: ", to.String(res.Type))
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I am using Goland and trying to run the app in WSL Ubuntu

Comment: I modified the imports as they should have been the following:

 "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/resources/mgmt/2020-10-01/resources"
 "github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/azure/auth"
 "github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/to"

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to use `auth.NewAuthorizerFromCLI()`, as `auth.NewAuthorizerFromEnvironment` does not use the Cli and MSI stands for managed system identity.

Comment: this might not work for some other people, whose code run in an environment where there is no Azure CLI available.

Answer (score 2):

Please read this documentation [Use environment-based authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/go/azure-sdk-authorization#use-environment-based-authentication)

You have a couple of options
and they need specific environments variables to be present.
In my case, I use Client credentials so I need to have these 3 envs present when I run my code.

1. `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`
2. `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`
3. `AZURE_TENANT_ID`

Comment: Yup got the same error, thanks for the info.
The variables must explicitly be available as environment variables.